# Spring Cron expression

Tags: spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

I need cron expression for triggering mail every 10th. but is that 10th is a weekend(saturday or sunday) then it has to be triggered two days before(if 10th is sat, then on thursday, and if 10th is sunday, then on friday)

Kindly help. This is my expression (0 0 12 10W 1/1 ? *). It checks for weekend and fires one day before. How to fire it two working days before

Comment: Try using - http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: I tried in cronmaker and could not find the exact expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your case this cannot be done with cron expression. Just do simple cron expression which will run every day and should check if the date is 10th of the month and do all needed checks manually.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it cannot be done. I have handled it in java

Comment: if (date.getDate() == 10
      && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY
      && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
     mailTrigger = true;
    } else if (date.getDate() == 8
      && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.THURSDAY) {
     mailTrigger = true;
    } else if (date.getDate() == 8
      && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
     mailTrigger = true;
    }

Answer (score 0):

How about two expressions? You could have `0 0 0 10 * MON-FRI` which fires on 10th when it is workday and `0 0 0 8 * THU-FRI` that fires when the weekend is 10th. That makes Thursday and Friday be on the 8th.

I hope this helps.